# Getting Module not found error when trying to import sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, jupyter, sklearn-pandas

I'm a windows user, I have been trying to use Jupyter-Notebook to perform operations that uses sklearn package. I have been running into module not found error even though I have it installed.

I installed it using

```
pip install sklearn
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
import sklearn.datasets as datasets

Getting following error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\WINDOW~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12348/2369316483.py in <module>
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      6 import seaborn as sns
----> 7 import sklearn.datasets as datasets
      8 import csv

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I tried checking if I have sklearn installed using

```
pip list

cycler          0.11.0
fonttools       4.29.1
joblib          1.1.0
kiwisolver      1.3.2
matplotlib      3.5.1
numpy           1.22.2
packaging       21.3
pandas          1.4.0
Pillow          9.0.1
pip             22.0.3
pyparsing       3.0.7
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2021.3
scikit-learn    1.0.2
scipy           1.8.0
seaborn         0.11.2
setuptools      41.2.0
six             1.16.0
sklearn         0.0
threadpoolctl   3.1.0
Unidecode       1.3.2
```

Comment: Maybe try to run ```help('modules')``` in python to check that it sees the same modules

Comment: This is probably because Jupyter's modules are not installed in the same path of the python that's added to your path. In order to check the installed packages on Jupyter's try to do this `!pip list`. And to install the module you want, do `!pip install <module name>`

Comment: @MohamedMostafa's advice is outdated. **Current best practice** is to use `%pip install` in a cell in your notebook for issues such as this. Similar holds for conda to use the modern magics in these cases, i.e., `%conda install` now, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Comment: Thank you so much @Wayne

Comment: @Wayne, Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

use
`pip install scikit-learn`
because, scikit-learn is the actual package name and should be used with pip